# Generic function in Go with type parameter being slice or not

Tags: go, generics

I've been trying to create this function that would convert between types at runtime. The types that it converts towards could be anything in principle, including slices of my own types.
The internal function `toSlice` would take care of the slices:

```golang
func toSlice[T any](toPtr *[]T, s []any) error {
    *toPtr = make([]T, len(s))
    for i, e := range s {
        if te, ok := e.(T); ok {
            (*toPtr)[i] = te
        } else {
            return fmt.Errorf("element at %d of type %T cannot be converted to %T",
                i, e, *new(T))
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Now I only have to distinguish between slices and non-slices at runtime and do the proper conversion. I'm trying like this:

```golang
func ToTypeVersion1[T any, P any](obj any) (T, error) {
    if s, ok := obj.([]any); ok {
        // This is a slice.
        to := *new(T)
        toSlice(&to, s) // does NOT build: type *T of &to does not match *[]T (cannot infer T)
        return to, nil
    }
    if o, ok := obj.(T); ok {
        return o, nil
    }
    return *new(T), fmt.Errorf("cannot convert from %T into %T", obj, *new(T))
}
```

Fails building, so I tried specifying T as being also a slice like this:

```golang
func ToTypeVersion2[T any | ~[]P, P any](obj any) (T, error) {
    if s, ok := obj.([]any); ok {
        // This is a slice.
        to := []P{}
        toSlice(&to, s)
        return to, nil //  does NOT build: cannot use to (variable of type []P) as type T in return statement
    }
    if o, ok := obj.(T); ok {
        return o, nil
    }
    return *new(T), fmt.Errorf("cannot convert from %T into %T", obj, *new(T))
}
```

If this wasn't enough, I also want its usage to be as simple as possible, and so I'd like the caller to only specify the type to be returned, like this:

```golang
ToTypeVersion2[[]int]([]any{myType(1), myType(2)}) // does NOT build: cannot infer P
```

In my mind having the compiler inferring the type of P from T being `[]int`, because the other options would just not compile (similar to SFINAE in C++).

Would something like `ToTypeVersion2` exist in Go?
What about the type inference of `P` à la SFINAE?

(go playground: https://go.dev/play/p/E-rOQKtFiY- )